# docker port command returning nothing

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

I am following the tutorial [here.](https://github.com/docker/labs/blob/master/beginner/chapters/webapps.md)

In this, you launch a container like so :

```
docker run --name static-site -e AUTHOR="Your Name" -d -P dockersamples/static-site
e61d12292d69556eabe2a44c16cbd54486b2527e2ce4f95438e504afb7b02810
```

which I have done. Then it tells you to run the command :

```
docker port static-site
```

This is meant to return the ports the container is running on, right ?

It's returning nothing for me. How come ?

`sudo docker ps -l` shows it has been created.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What does `docker container inspect e61d12292d` output, also try `docker container inspect static-site` in case it is different? Please edit your question with the output.

Comment: For future readers, check if you've specified --net="host". Port mapping has no use when using host networking, as your container is using the host's network stack. Meaning when your app listens on a port, it's listening on the host's port.

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, I have following results:

```
$ docker run --name static-site -e AUTHOR="Your Name" -d -P dockersamples/static-site
ac25e7cdd81725dfa157ff7027d1ed6beb3839c9457b9627728d700375e7a77f

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                           NAMES
ac25e7cdd817        dockersamples/static-site   "/bin/sh -c 'cd /usr…"   6 seconds ago       Up 5 seconds        0.0.0.0:32774->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32773->443/tcp   static-site

$ docker port static-site
443/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32773
80/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:32774
```

Please inspect the result of the column 'ports' of the command `docker ps` on your machine where ports and the mapped ports are also displayed.